# PHP file using content-type: text/css breaks with newest version (13) of Microsoft Edge

Tags: php, css

I need to pull CSS variables from a database and compile a dynamic stylesheet with those styles. I've always used a PHP file to query those styles and then output that with a header content-type: text/css.

```
header("Content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8");
```

With the latest release of Microsoft Edge, version 13, this method no longer seems to be working. Any idea why or what I can use in place of this technique?

The technique is explained in more detail here: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/supercharge-your-css-with-php-under-the-hood--net-6409

The style sheet (PHP file output as CSS) is completely blank when viewing the source, but only in Edge version 13. All other browsers continue to work just fine.

Comment: I don't have Edge 13 here, but I'd start with checking if there were any differences between the HTTP headers of a real CSS file and this one. Do you use a BOM; if so, try it without one. Or, maybe Edge checks the filename extension. In that case, see what happens if you let Edge believe the extension is css, e.g. by putting the php file as index.php in a directory ending in .css

Comment: I think Edge checks the extensions. I was able to change the file extension to .css from .php and it loaded just fine (although I couldn't parse the PHP in the file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the implementation of the dynamic CSS file. In the example cited above, I'm using a link to a CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.php">
```

Edge seems to check the file extension and fails to load the css styles because the file extension isn't .css. To work around this, I used PHP to include the file instead:

```
include 'style.php';
```

Then within the PHP file, simply echo style tags around the CSS code.

```
<style>
     .class {
          property: none;
     }
</style>
```

This implementation is fundamentally different in that the styles are no longer included in a separate file when viewing the page source from the browser, but rather are displayed inline within the head section of the page.

This was the only way I was able to get dynamic styles generated with PHP to work with Microsoft Edge. Please post alternate solutions if anyone else has found another method.