# Render css with php header(“Content-type: text/css”) IE issue - when?

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am trying to render css with php file:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8");
?>
/*CSS GOES HERE*/
```

It works fine on my side in all browsers, but I have read some people are having the problem with IE and Edge:

[PHP file using content-type: text/css breaks with newest version (13) of Microsoft Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356866/php-file-using-content-type-text-css-breaks-with-newest-version-13-of-microso)

[header("Content-type: text/css"); is working in Firefox and Chrome, but in Internet Explorer 9 it shows up as 'text/html'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413107/headercontent-type-text-css-is-working-in-firefox-and-chrome-but-in-inter?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I am trying to reproduce the problem because I need cross browser solution, this code will be used on 100 different sites. But to find solution I need to reproduce the problem first. Under which situation this problem shows up?

Comment: Have you tried `header("Content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8", true);`

Comment: Yes I have this inside, with true or without. Please read my question again, I am trying to find out a situation when css from php file with `header("Content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8");` won't be rendered. In my side it works always, but I need to find out situation when it doesn't work so I can find solution also for those cases.